# Interpolation animation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interpolation, unityscript

I am attempting to learn how to create animations in Unity by interpolating between two sets of joint positions of my head model. My first step into this is to simply move the jaw joint down to a given position and back up over time. However, I am completely new to using models and animations in general, so any assistance would be a huge help to me. Linear interpolation is fine. I just don't know how to get something like this set up in Unity.

I have attached the model head I am using.
[.fbx file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bykcus5EO99mNDBPd19UMm1sUm8/edit?usp=drive_web)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try autokey animation? (i'm not shure "autokey" is right term for unity). Something like shown in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaKDttsEwCs) video

Comment: Later I will be provided with a set of models that are in the position of the English speaking phonemes. The goal was to have some rough animation between phonemes to animate speaking. We had figured that it would be easier to call an interpolation function to move the model to the location of the next phoneme instead of storing all of the possible animations from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the animation, if it's something simple, you can animate via script by changing the positions of the model code and doing so via interpolation.
However, if you want something more complex, you can use the Mecanim Unity which is very good, see: http://video.unity3d.com/video/7362044/.

Or use the tool animation: "Window" -> "Animation".  (CTRL + 6)

Remember that to use the Mecanim of unity is necessary to have Unity Pro, but the "animation" does not.

Hope this helps !